# Windows 10: Force-Disable Palm Rejection

Tags: windows-10, drivers, touchpad

I recently purchased an Asus VivoBook S14 which uses their own AsusPTP precision touchpad driver. I've reinstalled the driver countless times, tweaked the touchpad sensitivity, and disabled every mouse gesture setting I could find. Unfortunately the palm rejection is still an issue. Everything I've seen has referred to Settings panels or options that no longer exist, tabs in the old control panel that aren't relevant or present on my system, or registry keys that don't exist (as well they shouldn't as they are for a different driver).

Is there a way to *force* it to disable palm rejection? Having to wait up *10 seconds* for Windows to make the decision for me that I really do want to use the touchpad is unacceptable.